# Fair concurrent `map` function in haskell?

Tags: haskell, concurrency, non-deterministic

Say I am simulating a network of some sort, and have a function which broadcasts a value over a list of Chans:

```
broadcast :: a -> [Receiver] -> IO ()
broadcast a = mapM_ (send a)
```

This will "send" the data to each Receiver in order. I would like instead to broadcast nondeterministically to all of the Receivers.

Thanks for any clues.

Answer (score 3):

How about just using GHC's concurrency?

```
broadcast :: a -> [Receiver] -> IO ()
broadcast a = mapM_ (forkIO . send a)
```

Then make sure to use the threaded RTS (compile with `ghc -threaded`).

Comment: That introduces some nondeterminism, sure, and for certain applications I can see it being the right way. But I'd suspect that the order in which messages are received, while nondeterministic, would generally stick pretty close to a linear ordering. If you want to ensure that things are mixed up, better to do so explicitly.

Comment: Perhaps also introduce a random delay after forking off each thread? Your solution makes sense for this restricted scenario, but I suspect that once you introduce any complications like communication, it won't generalise.

Answer (score 2):

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-shuffle-0.0.2

```
broadcast a rs = do 
   g <- newStdGen
   mapM_ (send a) $ shuffle' rs (length rs) g
```